# JavaScript: Set background colour of <td> in table containing <select> based upon which <option> is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not familiar with JavaScript but the software im writing generates a big table in a html file so im having a go at using JavaScript for some styling and behaviours within.

The html file contains a large table of data.
One of the rows  of the table contains a  drop down box with three (s) with correlated colours:

pass : green |
fail : red |
none : blue

As a visual aid for the user I am trying to set the background colour of the  containing the  to map to the colour of the selected item. 
When the programme starts some of the drop down boxes will be set to pass or fail (or none), Therefore the JavaScript must Set the td background color mapping to the select box :

- when the document is first rendered within the browser.
- When a select box selected value is changed

So far ive got as far as :

```
<td align="center" id="dropdownTableData">
    <select id = "select" onchange="setColor()">
        <option value="green">pass</option>
        <option value="red">fail</option>
        <option value="blue" selected="selected">none</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

with the JavaScript :

```
setColor = function() {
    var e = document.getElementById("select");
    e.style.backgroundColor = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

Apologies if this is fairly simple but I'm still trying to wrap my head around JavaScript.

**EDIT**

Now solved (in various ways) see solutions below!

Comment: Do you want to change the background color of the `cell` containing the `select` or the background color of the whole `row`?

Comment: just the <td></td> cell

Comment: If your question was answered please accept the best one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your HTML a bit so it becomes dynamic:

```
<td align="center" id="dropdownTableData">
    <select id = "select" onchange="setColor(this)">
        <option value="green">pass</option>
        <option value="red">fail</option>
        <option value="blue" selected="selected">none</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

JS:

```
setColor = function(element) {
    element.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

Invoke on the start:

```
var selectElements = document.getElementById('tableID').getElementsByTagName('select')
for (var i = 0; i < selectElements.length; i++) {
    setColor(selectElements[i]);
}
```

Just a small side note:

Although my answer fixes the problems that are stated in the question, I believe the answer that [Chase Ingebritson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51771108/1336174) gave is more elegant and easier to maintain in the future.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. This works great onhange, exactly what im looking for there.  How do i then invoke the setColor(this) method for each <td id="dropdownTableData"> when the html file is ready in the browser. IE if "pass" is selected the background will be set to the corresponding green (and vice versa for fail, none etc)?

Comment: @NathanOrmond I added that part. Sorry for reading over it the first time

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend changing the `classList` of the `parentNode` based on the value of your element.

To listen for a change in your `<select>`, it may be a bit cleaner to add an event listener to each one. Once your select changes, just call a function that gets the parent, gets the value, and changes the class of your parent based on the value of your element.

```js
var data = document.querySelectorAll('#data-table tr td select');

data.forEach(function(item) {
  setColor(item);

  item.addEventListener('change', function() {
    setColor(this);
  });
});

function setColor(element) {
  var container = element.parentElement;
  container.classList.remove('none', 'pass', 'fail');

  var value = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
  container.classList.add(value);
}
```

```css
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

table tr td.none {
  background-color: blue;
}

table tr td.pass {
  background-color: green;
}

table tr td.fail {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="data-table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="none" default selected>None</option>
        <option value="pass">Pass</option>
        <option value="fail">Fail</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="none" default>None</option>
        <option value="pass" selected>Pass</option>
        <option value="fail">Fail</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="none" default>None</option>
        <option value="pass">Pass</option>
        <option value="fail" selected>Fail</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a really nice solution and I agree definitely makes things cleaner and easier to understand and maintain/change in future.

Comment: Thanks! Feel free to let me know if you have any questions on the implementation or mark it as a solution if you feel like it answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `parentNode` property:

```
setColor = function() {
         var e = document.getElementById("select");
         e.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
      }
```